# translate() function error

Tags: python

The translate function is giving me an error that I'm giving it 2 members and I should be passing it exactly 1.  This is the correct code based on the books I'm using currently.  I'm using Python 3.4.

```
import string
fhand=open("c:\Python34\Leos code\mbox.txt")
dictsort = dict()
#decorate dictionary
for line in fhand:
    line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in dictsort:
            dictsort[word]= 1
        else:
            dictsort[word] += 1
#sort dictionary
dictlst = []
for k,v in dictsort.items():
    dictlst.append((v,k))
dictlst.sort(reverse=True)
for k,v in dictlst[:10]:
    print (k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

A line of code should be added and the translate line modified:

```
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
line = line.translate(remove_punctuation_map)
```

There is a change in Python 3.x where a tuple needs to be passed to the translate function, so this needs to be created in a dictionary before and then passed to translate method.